# Could not add click event on dynamically created anchor tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, anchor

I am trying to register `click` event on `anchor` tag created dynamically but it is not working. Following is code

```
var location = 's';

$('#phone').on('click', 'a', function(event) {
  console.info('Anchor clicked!');
  event.preventDefault();
  return false;
});

for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  $("div#phone").append('<ul><a href="#" id = "' + location + '"> rajeev </a></ul>');
}
```

Have a look at [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rajeevinkomm/3oy472om/1/)

**Edit Updated Fiddle Link**

Comment: have you tried to simply put the event binding to the end of the file? Moreover you should not use multiple IDs

Comment: Put something in fiddle so someone can help you.

Comment: Your code runs ok. I create a jsfiddle to show but it seems as jsfiddle is not saving the fiddles.

Comment: What problem do you have? Your code is working fine!

Comment: But for me it is not showing any alert dialog

Comment: `console.info` won't show a dialog. For a dialog, use `alert('mesage')`

Comment: don't duplicate element ids, they must be unique

Comment: `console.info` throws a message in your javascript console. It is transparent for the user.

Comment: It does work see this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/3oy472om/

Comment: Thanks it works.. My fault actually..

Comment: Error: Element `a` not allowed as child of element `ul` in this context. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works well, check your browser's console or change the console for alert:

```
$('#phone').on('click', 'a', function(event) {
  alert('Anchor clicked!');
  event.preventDefault();
  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Works fine if you place your code after your loop.

https://jsfiddle.net/3oy472om/

```
for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  $("div#phone").append('<ul><a href="#" id = "' + location + '"> rajeev </a></ul>');
}

$('#phone a').on('click', function(event) {
  alert('Anchor clicked!');
  event.preventDefault();
  return false;
});
```